# duplicate table in sql with add new Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i can duplicate table like this:

```
create table abc_new as select * from abc
```

can i duplicate the table and new Columns like birthdate as date in the same sentences?

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?  Different RDBMS have different syntax and capabilities.  Also, do you want to duplicate just the basic structure, or also any indexes, foreign keys, other constraints, etc?

Comment: create table abc_new as select birthdate as new_date from abc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it add date

```
create table abc_new as select *,sysdate as someDate from abc
```

if i type number it add number..

Comment: This raises an 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected', because you need an alias for abc - just modify it to 'create table abc_new as select t1.*, sysdate as someDate from abc t1'

Answer (score 0):

You can create the view of the table in Sql . You cant create the duplicate table in Sql like Mysql.

for view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```